# How to use Date Pipes for some columns in PrimeNG table with dynamic number of columns

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am trying to display a dynamic number of columns, and also trying to use a `<ng-template ...` to specify how a cell is being rendered.But in my data set there are some fields belongs to date type. I want to format that fields using a date pipe.

html file

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
      <tr>
        <td *ngFor="let col of columns" [style.width]="col.width">
          {{rowData[col.field]| col?.pipe}}
        </td>
      </tr>
</ng-template>
```

typescript file (In the cols array, I would like to add another field like this.)

```
 this.cols = [
      { field: 'no', header: 'No.', width: '50px',pipe:null },
      { field: 'createdDate', header: 'createdDate', width: '175px', pipe: 'date: \'dd/MM/yyyy\''},
      { field: 'deviceName', header: 'Device Name', width: '150px'}
    ];
```

I've tried this and it gives me template parsing errors.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try like this

```js
this.cols = [
          { field: 'no', header: 'No.', width: '50px',pipe:null },
          { field: 'createdDate', header: 'createdDate', width: '175px', data: true , format: `dd/MM/yyyy`},
          { field: 'deviceName', header: 'Device Name', width: '150px'}
        ];
```

*template*

```html
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
      <tr>
        <td *ngFor="let col of columns" [style.width]="col.width">   
          {{ col.data ? (rowData[col.field]| date : col.format) : rowData[col.field] }}
        </td>
      </tr>
</ng-template>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/p-table-primeng-v6-aqfxcd)

Comment: @BinaraThambugala I have update the answer there was a typo `{{ col.data ? (rowData[col.field]| date : col.format) : rowData[col.field] }}`

Comment: @BinaraThambugala did you check my updated answer , do you still have a problem ?

Comment: @BinaraThambugala I will create a demo 

Comment: @BinaraThambugala |I have create a demo and it 's working fine 